# Rails 4 Comparing Datetime in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, datetime

Hi I am having issues comparing datetimes with a Rails 4 JSON API.

I use a scope with the created_at attribute

```
scope :later_than, -> (date) { where('created_at > ?', date) }
```

The JSON returned for the created_at looks like

```
"created_at" = "2015-05-07T01:16:43.611Z"
```

When sending this same datetime the API log and SQL look like

```
Parameters: {"later_than"=>"2015-05-06T21:16:43.611-0400"}

created_at > '2015-05-06T21:16:43.611-0400'
```

In the console

```
Object.first.created_at
=> Thu, 07 May 2015 01:16:43 UTC +00:00
Object.first.created_at > '2015-05-06T21:16:43.611-0400'
=> true
```

The last comparison should be false, but instead it is true and the scope is not working properly.

When logging

```
Object.first.created_at - '2015-05-06T21:16:43.611-0400'.to_datetime
=> 0.000402
```

So what happens is:

- the API returns datetime truncated to milliseconds
- Rails compares datetimes with microseconds precision

Thus when sending the same datetime to the API, the microseconds will be set to 0 and thus the comparison is not going to work as expected.

Is there a way to tell Rails: compare datetimes with millisecond precision?

Comment: You mean you just want to compare dates and not along with the times?

Comment: What happens right now : API returns a datetime truncated to milliseconds, but when sending datetimes to the API for comparison, Rails compares internally until microsecond, which is why the comparison is not working

Comment: you can use Ruby's `.floor` method on the value and compare if its >=0 and create a boolean on that?(might not be the ideal solution ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Is `Message.first.created_at` equal to `Thu, 07 May 2015 01:16:43 UTC +00:00`? (you have `Object.first.created_at` up there) because if it is, the console expression is behaving correctly and should be true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

`Object.first.created_at > Time.parse('2015-05-06T21:16:43.611-0400')`